# Can't award bounty, js error on page around "vote-sub"

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, bounties

I am unable to award a bounty to my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25894290/declaring-persistent-jpa-entities-in-applicationcontext-xml) on SO.

I tried it on two different systems (one has a direct connection and one connects through a proxy) and with a wide spectrum of different browsers (firefox, konqueror, explorer 8 and chrome).

In all cases, the confirm question ("this can't be undone") appeared perfectly, but after that nothing happened.

The most informative error message I've got is coming from a firebug:

[image]

Explorer 8 gives the following error message:

[image]

What to do now?

Comment: IE 8 is not supported so not relevant. Can you try with IE10 or 11?

Comment: @Sha http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272415/bug-while-trying-to-award-a-bounty?cb=1 something similar

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thank you the comment. I don't have access to one, so probably not, but I will try.

Comment: @nicael Thank you - looks the same mysterious thing. In my case, the problem happened on a _wide_ scale of different browsers/systems (around 5 different configurations), most of them didn't contained any of my SE sessions.

Comment: Question is if it happens in other sites, if only on Stack Overflow it should be reported only in MSO.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Actually, my only way to test that is to create a new bounty on another SE site.

Comment: @nicael it's clear the bug is in the JS code itself and not browser related. Surprised it didn't get any real attention yet.

Comment: As a workaround, you can try unaccepting and accepting the answer again, as far as I remember it's asking you if to award the bounty in such case and even if not, when you accept an answer during bounty period, it should be fully awarded to that answer when the time expire.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I've tried it, but it wasn't asked. Also I tried to award the bounty after unaccept and a full page reload, but it also didn't change anything.

Comment: Let's hope that either the bug is fixed in the next 29 hours, or I'm right to assume it would be auto awarded to the accepted answer then. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes but in this case I won't get probably a copper badge... I will miss that. :-)

Comment: Oh, that's right. Hopefully the dev fixing the bug will be gracious enough to give you the badge manually ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ouch, that's bad, sorry about that. Fixed now.